# Cómo pasar texto de Activity a Fragment con pestañas?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment

Buenas tardes queridos programadores.
tengo tres fragment para mostrar en pestañas mediante ViewPager. En "Fragment 1" tengo una listView y en el toobar del Activity tengo un SearchView.
Lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente: Buscar con el SearchView (toolbar de activity) en el Listview (Fragment 1).

¿COMO PUEDO PASAR TEXTO AL FRAGMENT EN TIEMPO DE EJECUCIÓN?

la siguiente es como se ve..
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código

```
public class BuscarClienteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private SearchView BuscarLV;
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private Bundle bltextoFr = new Bundle();
public Context context;


private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_buscar_cliente);
    BuscarLV = (SearchView)findViewById(R.id.SearLVCliente);
    BuscarLV.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            
            bltextoFr.putString("textob",s);// Este es el texto que quiero enviar al Fragment
            mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.i(Constantes.TAG,"prueba arg 2");
            return false;
        }
    });

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

   
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);


    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    context = getApplicationContext();

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_buscar_cliente, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }



    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);

        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_buscar_cliente, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public Context context = getApplicationContext();
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        //return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                FragmentBuscarClientesAll f1 = new FragmentBuscarClientesAll();


                return FragmentBuscarClientesAll.newInstance(bltextoFr.getString("textob"));//aquí supongo que debe recibir el objeto Bundle para enviar al Fragment
            case 1:
                FragmentBuscarClientesMorosos fmoroso= new FragmentBuscarClientesMorosos();
                return fmoroso;
            case 2:
                FragmentBuscarClientesOtros fOtros = new FragmentBuscarClientesOtros();
                return fOtros;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Clientes";
            case 1:
                return "Morosos";
            case 2:
                return "Otros";
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

}

La clase Fragment que deseo recibir el texto en tiempo real:

```
public class FragmentBuscarClientesAll extends Fragment {
private ListView LvClientesAll;
private BuscarClientesAdapter adapter;
private SearchView BuscarLV;
private RadioButton RB_nombre,RB_ci;
private BuscarClienteActivity b = new BuscarClienteActivity();
Context C;
private static String KEY_REG_TEXT = "textob";
private Button btnp;


public static FragmentBuscarClientesAll newInstance(String text) {
    FragmentBuscarClientesAll frag = new FragmentBuscarClientesAll();

    Bundle args =new Bundle();
            frag.getArguments();
    if(args == null)
        args = new Bundle();

    args.putString(KEY_REG_TEXT, text);

    frag.setArguments(args);

    return frag;
}
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    C = context;
    if (C==null){
        Log.i(Constantes.TAG,"Context null -2");
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    BaseDeDatos BD = new BaseDeDatos(C, ContratoBD.DBNAME,null,ContratoBD.DB_VERSION);
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_buscar_cliente,container,false);
    LvClientesAll = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.LsClientesAll);
    View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_buscar_cliente,null);

    RB_nombre = (RadioButton)v.findViewById(R.id.RB_Nombre);
    RB_ci = (RadioButton)v.findViewById(R.id.RB_CI);
    btnp =(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnP);

    List<ClientesClass> ListaRecuperadas = new ArrayList<>();
    if (C==null){
        Log.i(Constantes.TAG,"Context null");
    }
    //BD.Abrir();
    ListaRecuperadas = BD.ListaClientes();
    //BD.Cerrar();

    if (!(ListaRecuperadas==null)){
        adapter = new BuscarClientesAdapter(ListaRecuperadas,C);
        LvClientesAll.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    
    //Aqui donde supondo recibir
    
    String texto="";
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    if (args != null) {
        texto = args.getString(KEY_REG_TEXT);
    }
    Log.i(Constantes.TAG,"prueba textob"+texto);



            if (RB_nombre.isChecked()){
                adapter.BuscarPor =0;
                                }
            if (RB_ci.isChecked()){
                adapter.BuscarPor =1;

            }
            adapter.getFilter().filter(texto);




            /*BuscarLV.setIconified(true);
            BuscarLV.onActionViewCollapsed();*/
            //BuscarLV.clearFocus();
            //BuscarLV.setClipToOutline(false);


    return v;
}
```

}

por favor, Gracias!!

Comment: Hola Joel, en el sitio ya se tiene información de lo que preguntas : https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=fragment.setArguments%28bundle%29%3B  Saludos!

Comment: Gracias por su comentario, pero aún no puedo solucionar :(

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
Fragement fragment = new AgregarBienesServicios();
fragmentTransaction = true;
String string = "texto1";
bundle.putString("key","texto");
bundle.putString("key1","string");
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
    replace(R.id.contenedor,fragment).commit();
```

Para recuperar en los fragments seria algo como:
en el onCreate:

```
    if (getArguments()!=null){
        String string1 = getArguments().getString("key","cualquiertxt1");
        String string2 = getArguments().getString("key1","cualquiertxt");
    }
```